# Imported dependency requires another dependency to be first available in scope

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to import [a library that extends another one](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-layers/blob/master/dist/pixi-layers.js), here's my first approach:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import 'pixi-layers'; // extends PIXI classes
```

I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined` on runtime when `pixi-layers` tries to `Object.assign` on a PIXI class.

I suppose this is related to how webpack's hoisting, I've tried to use:

- [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/)
- [script-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/)
- I've also tried to provide PIXI through webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            PIXI: 'pixi.js',
        }),
    ],
};
```

PIXI remains unavailable to `pixi-layers`, how can I bundle `pixi-layers` and make sure it can actually work with the PIXI object?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out providing PIXI as a plugin through the webpack config file *was* the solution, I just has this same config file compile in the wrong location (paths are hard).